# How to solve dependent state updates "the react way"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, use-effect, setstate

I stumbled upon a very interesting question and I would like to know how to best solve this in React. Assume the following code:

```
const [qrText, setQrText] = useState("")

...

const generateQrCode = () => {
  // set other state inside the "then"
  QRCode.toDataUrl(qrText).then(...)
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setQrText(e.target.value)
  generateQrCode()
}
```

This code is unsafe, since state updates are asynchronously, and by the time `generateQrCode` runs, `qrText` could still have the old value.

I always tended to solve this problem using a `useEffect` with dependency array:

```
const [qrText, setQrText] = useState("")

...

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setQrText(e.target.value)
}

useEffect(() => {
  const generateQrCode = () => {
    // set other state inside the "then"
    QRCode.toDataUrl(qrText).then(...)
  }
  generateQrCode()
}, [qrText])
```

However, I recently watched a [YouTube video from a React conference](https://youtu.be/HPoC-k7Rxwohttps://youtu.be/HPoC-k7Rxwo), where a senior engineer said that `useEffect` is only supposed to be used to synchronize data with external services or the DOM. Instead, people should update state in **event handlers** only.

So is this the right way then to handle this scenario?

```
const [qrText, setQrText] = useState("")

...

// this now takes the qrText as argument
const generateQrCode = (qrTextArg) => {
  // set other state inside the "then"
  QRCode.toDataUrl(qrTextArg).then(...)
}

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value
  setQrText(value)
  generateQrCode(value) // pass the event value, instead of relying on the "qrText" state
}
```

This would equal the "event based" approached, but feels a bit imperative and not "react"-ish.

So I wonder, what is the intended way to do this?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Yes, your last example is the recommended way to handle it. Though depending on what happens in the `then` you may want to refactor a little (say, await the generateQrCode and then set all states together). Relevant documentation: [React: Where you can cause side effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-can-cause-side-effects)

Comment: hi, in class component, there exist a callback fn that gets fired once the state is updated, but no such setup in functional components, you've to use useEffect, or you can create a custom hook and pass input event value as a dep

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the ressource you shared, it's greatly appreciated. Speaking about updating the state together, since in this case qrText and the other state would change together, do you recommend to also put them into the same state? So to basically have an object with both qrText and the other state in it?